# Why does gradle use 2 local caches?

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle

I am about a week into learning Gradle, and so far I really like the tool.  However there is one thing that I don't particularly like and I am wondering if its my own misunderstanding.  Here are the facts:

1) I have 2 projects:  commonjar and webapp.  Webapp requires commonjar.
2) neither build.gradle contains mavenLocal() in the repo section.
3) 'gradle clean install' on commonjar places the jar in the .m2 repo
4) 'gradle cleanEclipse eclipse install' on webapp downloads an older version of the jar from nexus and places it in .gradle repo and set the eclipse classpath to use the older .gradle version.

Here are my questions:

No matter what I try, I can't seem to make eclipse use the latest local version of commonjar.

1)  Should I spend my efforts trying to make "gradle install" push the common jar to .gradle?
2) Or would it be better to find a way for 'gradle eclispe' on the webapp project use the jar that ended up in the .m2 repo?
3) And lastly, what possible benefit do I get from having both .m2 and .gradle (this seems like a bad idea at first glance)?

Thanks in advance,
Bob

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though Gradle works with Maven, it keeps it at arm's length.

Gradle keeps its own copy of the artifacts, for long-term use, to remove a whole host of hard-to-debug issues that could occur due to changes in the external Maven repository. Disk space is cheap these days, so the duplication of the jars isn't considered too much of an issue. In any case, you don't need to have a local Maven repository to use Gradle.

It is also worth noting that the Maven code is not under Gradle developer's control and historically has been plagued with reliability problems (upgrades that break etc.)

To answer your question about how to organize the code. I would set up a multi-project Gradle build and have the projects depend on each other. The Gradle eclipse plugin will automatically create the appropriate `.classpath` file.

```
project(':webapp') {
    dependencies {
        compile project(':commonjar')
    }
}
```

Comment: I gave this a shot and it solves half the issue.  It adds the correct and latest jar from .m2 to the eclipse classpath, but it also adds an outdated commonjar-sources.jar from the .gradle repo.  Any ideas?

Comment: Hmm, it sounds like it has got its knickers in a twist. Try using `--refresh-dependencies` on the command-line.